# Can we format, in VBA, a query field properties after it is create?

Tags: vba, ms-access

In Access, when creating a new query using vba, some of the data I'm getting are currency, but it comes by default as *General Number*. I would like to change it's format like we can do in the *Property Sheet*, but I can't seem to find a way.

I have tried

```
db.QueryDefs("TestQuery").Fields("SumOfSomething").Type = DAO.dbCurrency
```

But then I get: `Run-time error '3219': Invalid operation.`

I have searched around a bit and found a similar question (but couldn't find it back) to which the answer was that you can't change that after it is created. I fail to see the point of having the possibility to change the type if we can't actually do it.

So, in the end, can we change (in VBA) the properties of a field after the query is created?

Comment: Please don't ask multi-barreled questions. Changing the variable type is a very different issue from changing the formatting. Some properties can be changed, others can't, and for those that can't, there are workarounds. But one at a time, please.

Comment: Why don't you change it in the query `CCur([SumOfSomething])` - just because you can see the property doesn't mean you have the right to change it - may have heard of read-only? You can also change the qdf SQL on the fly if you have your heart set on changing it after creation.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Sorry, i now have change my question to only the main problem. Rounding in my query definition actually does the same thing as far as i know so i got that problem out of the way.

So my main problem now is showing result as Currency in my query. I am able to change it by hand just by going in the desing view and change the format to currency, but i'm wondering if there is a way to do it in VBA.

Comment: @CedL Do you mean _formatting as currency_ or _changing the data type to currency_? Those are very different things.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I would say format it? Like for exemple, you can show the data as percent or euro or, as i'd like, currency. So this way it will show the value with a dollar sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question appears to be simple, but as you've probably guessed by now, it isn't.

The format property is a custom property of a field. They can be present, and if they are, they should be changed using the `Field.Properties` collection, but if they aren't, they need to be created using `Field.CreateProperty` method and then appended to the `Fields.Properties` collection

```
Const currencyFormat As String = "€ #,##0.00;€ #,##0.00-"'Dutch currency format, you need to set this for your locale
Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef
Set qd = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("TestQuery")
On Error Resume Next
qd.Fields("SumOfSomething").Properties!Format = currencyFormat
If Err.Number = 3270 Then 'Property not found, field had no format set
    qd.Fields("SumOfSomething").Properties.Append qd.Fields("SumOfSomething").CreateProperty("Format", dbText, currencyFormat)
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

You can get the currency format for your locale by setting a field to use it, and then using `?CurrentDb.QueryDefs("TestQuery").Fields("SumOfSomething").Properties!Format`

Comment: Just to make sure, `"€ #,##0.00;€ #,##0.00-"`  means we allow 2 decimal, every 3 number (sorry, cant remember the term) are divided by comma and the money sign is on front?

Comment: @CedL Honestly, it corresponds with the _Currency_ format option in the dropdown for my locale, but I haven't analyzed it. You can see at the bottom how I acquired it. It's also identical to the _Euro_ format option. I suggest you first print out the formatting for your locale, and then just use that.

Comment: Aside from # , the rest is pretty easy to understand. Left side is how you show the positive value, right one for negative. Money sign for where it should be. The zeroes are pretty much what you would think. Imagine having 0,21 but you setted your format at 00.00 , it will show 00,21

Answer (score 0):

We have to be clear here on the goal. Do you want to “just” cast or change the column type returned in a query, or do you want to modify the actual column type in the database table? These are two VERY different goals.

To use code to modify a column type, you have to create (add) the new column type, transfer the data, and then delete the old column, and then re-name the column back to the old type.

In other words, you can’t just change the data type, since Access will THEN have to update each and every row to the new data type.

The UI system in fact does the above behind the scenes.

If you use DAO code, then you need the following code outlined here:

http://accessblog.net/2007/03/how-to-change-field-type-using-dao.html

However, above is quite a bit of code. In place of DAO code to add the column, you CAN use a DDL command.

(SQL data definition language) to modify the type. Thus in code you can do this:

```
Dim db         As dao.Database
Dim strSQL     As String

Set db = CurrentDb

strSQL = "ALTER TABLE dbo_tblHotels1 ALTER COLUMN MyAmount currency"
db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

So in above, we change the column "MyAmount" to currency type.